# Can't access ubuntu after dual-booting with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

So, when I start my computer, it takes me to the grub screen, in which I can choose between ubuntu and windows; it works just fine with windows, but if I select ubuntu, the computer reboots and takes me back to the grub screen. What is happening?

Edit: What happened was, I had both windows and ubuntu installed, deleted ubuntu but then I couldn't access windows either; so I had a few problems but managed to get the windows boot usb to work and install windows again; after that, I installed ubuntu, and the present problem persists.

Comment: Did you install Windows after installing Ubuntu and/or did Windows have a major update?  Both can mess up grub/boot files.  Edit your question and say if Ubuntu did work before or this is a new install that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can repair Grub from the Ubuntu installation disk, or use my favorite:

https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/  where you can download a bootable CD image.  It repairs both MBR and UEFI boot setups.  Usually, the default recovery will do the job.  If not, you can fiddle with the advanced options.

I use the advanced options only to kill off a few features I don't care to use.

Comment: I followed the instructions, it all went well but still can't access ubuntu :(

Comment: Then the problem might not be with Grub.  cnp659's comment seems on the mark.  Maybe you should answer his question.